Ping request could not find the host in Windows 10
ping hostname]1 From CMD, when I ping the hostname, I am sometimes able to find the host, but other times I cannot. What could be causing this issue? (see attached figure).
The following are my network configuration
Wifi-properties 
Ethernet properties 
